# Is it bad practice to pass php variables into values of html input tags?

Tags: javascript, php, html

The thought of making yet another get request and yet another php file is annoying to me... so I've been using this method:

```
<input class='hidden' id='dataIwant' value=' <?php echo $_SESSION["bigObjectArray"] ?>" />
```

Is this bad practice?  What do you think?

Comment: don't forget 2 things : 1 : the value can contains `"` and break HTML, 2 : the value of this hidden field can be modified by the user before to be send with the form

Comment: is it array `$_SESSION["bigObjectArray"]`?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, session variables might be dangerous to display in the client side. Only part of them such as indexes, strings which the user already knows should be shown to the user. If the session variable contains something like user password, session token etc., it should be hidden.

About your question, it changes when where you want to use this data. If it's only for passing it inside the form to another PHP page, you don't need to do this, as it will still be available in the form processing page.

If you want to use it inside the javascript code in the client side, you can json_encode it and assign it to a javascript variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var myBigJSON = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION["bigObjectArray"]);?>;
   var myBigArray = $.parseJSON(myBigJSON);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this example speaks for itself:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['bigObjectArray'] = "\" /><script>alert('Hi!')</script><input type=\"hidden";
?>
<input class="hidden" id="dataIwant" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["bigObjectArray"] ?>" />
```

output:

`<input class="hidden" id="dataIwant" value="" /><script>alert('Hi!')</script><input type="hidden" />`

Make sure to validate and filter the data you are echoing. *Be paranoid, always*.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad pratice if you do not escape it (`htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars`).

It's a bad practice if user have no reason to change this field.

It's a bad practice for multi-tab browsing, since it's `SESSION` stored (concurrent pages writing/reading that value will fail).

It's a good practice if you html escape the value, if the user can change that field (and if you check it on the treatment page) and if it avoids storing that value in `SESSION`.